# Ggplot2 change the position of y axis values after removing gridlines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a heatmap in ggplot2 without the gridlines. I removed them using the theme function and panel.grid arguments, but it leaves the space between the y axis values and the plot:
[image]

I tried to close this gap using axis.text argument of theme function, but it makes the values not aligned:
[image]

Can someone please suggest a solution that would make the plot look like this:
[image]

Below the reproducible code:

```
library(ggplot2)
tmp<-data.frame(cbind(rep(c("Sun", "Sat", "Fri", "Thu", "Wed", "Tue", "Mon"), 24),
                      rep(0:23, 7),
                      runif(168, 0, 3)))
tmp$X1<-factor(tmp$X1, levels= c("Sun", "Sat", "Fri", "Thu", "Wed", "Tue", "Mon"))
tmp$X2<-as.numeric(tmp$X2)
tmp$X3<-as.numeric(tmp$X3)
ggplot(tmp, aes(X2, X1, fill=X3, label=round(X3,2))) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="springgreen", high="darkgreen") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:23) +
  geom_text() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        #axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 3.2),
        legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like that?

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(factor(X2 - 1), X1, fill = X3, label = round(X3, 2))) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "springgreen", high = "darkgreen") +
  coord_fixed(.5) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.background   = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x       = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y       = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks         = element_blank(),
    legend.position    = "none"
  )
```

[image: heatmap]

The problem with y-lab spacing is due to the fact that your `X2` var is continuous. So `geom_tile()` positions the center of your tiles at 1, 2, 3...23, with the width of a tile == 1. The left side of the first tile starts at 1 - .5 = 0.5, that is why there is an empty place between -.5 and .5 (no tiles with center at 0). Converting `X2` into factor, will fix it without any additional readjustment.

You might want to fix margins of the plot, thought.